# When reading 4-channel tif file, value different from SKIMAGE, TIFFFILE and so on

Tags: opencv, tiff, scikit-image

I know the opencv got a BGR order, but in my experiment, not only the order but also the values are totally messed

```
import cv2 as cv
import tifffile as tiff
import skimage.io

img_path = r"C:\test\pics\t100r50s16_1_19.tif"
c = cv.imread(img_path,cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
t = tiff.imread(img_path)
s = skimage.io.imread(img_path)

print("c:", c.shape, "t:", t.shape, "s:", s.shape)
print("c:", c.dtype, "t:", t.dtype, "s:", s.dtype)

print(c[0, 0], c[1023, 0], c[0, 1023], c[1023, 1023])
print(t[0, 0], t[1023, 0], t[0, 1023], t[1023, 1023])
print(s[0, 0], s[1023, 0], s[0, 1023], s[1023, 1023])

print(c.sum())
print(t.sum())
print(s.sum())
```

And the outputs like this:

```
c: (1024, 1024, 4) t: (1024, 1024, 4) s: (1024, 1024, 4)
c: uint8 t: uint8 s: uint8
[ 50  63  56 182] [131 137 140 193] [29 28 27 94] [123 130 134 190]
[ 79  88  70 182] [185 181 173 193] [74 77 80 94] [180 174 165 190]
[ 79  88  70 182] [185 181 173 193] [74 77 80 94] [180 174 165 190]
# Here seems that opencv only read the alpha channel right, 
# the values of first three channels are much different than other package

539623146
659997127
659997127
```

The image i use can be download [here](https://github.com/ziyigogogo/imgs/blob/master/t100r50s16_1_19.tif). So, here is my question, how open cv handle 4 channel tiff file? Because when i test on 3-channel image, everything looks alright.

Comment: The order is "BGR", not "GBR".

Comment: This is apparently a known issue, at least for JPEG. It is probably due to the different decoder these two libraries use to decode the image. See [this link](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2293) for a discussion.

Comment: Thank you for pointing my mistake and providing reference @lightalchemist

Comment: And actually i have looked into the link you provide yesterday, in that discussion, the differences seems caused by "round" issue(probably caused by dtype), because the value diff in minor(like 49 and 50, 101 and 100). But in my situation the gap is so big(130 and 174, 28 and 77 in G channel). And this only happens in 4-channel image, when i changed to 3-channel everything works fine. So that's why i open a new question here@lightalchemist

Comment: Can you supply a 3-channel TIFF that works correctly too please - I think I have something...

Answer (score 6):

I don't buy it for a minute that there is a rounding error or some error related to JPEG decoding like the linked article suggests.

Firstly because your image is integer, specifically `uint8` so there is no rounding of floats, and secondly because the compression of your TIF image is not JPEG - in fact there is no compression. You can see that for yourself if you use **ImageMagick** and do:

```
identify -verbose a.tif
```

or if you use `tiffinfo` that ships with `libtiff`, like this:

```
tiffinfo -v a.tif
```

So, I did some experiments by generating sample images with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
# Make 8x8 pixel TIF full of RGBA(64,128,192) with full opacity
convert -depth 8 -size 8x8 xc:"rgba(64,128,192,1)" a.tif

# Make 8x8 pixel TIFF with 4 rows per strip
convert -depth 8 -define tiff:rows-per-strip=4 -size 8x8 xc:"rgba(64,128,192,1)" a.tif
```

And **OpenCV** was able to read all those correctly, however, when I did the following it went wrong.

```
# Make 8x8 pixel TIFF with RGB(64,128,192) with 50% opacity
convert -depth 8 -define tiff:rows-per-strip=1 -size 8x8 xc:"rgba(64,128,192,0.5)" a.tif
```

And the values came out in **OpenCV** as 32, 64, 96 - yes, exactly **HALF** the correct values - like **OpenCV** is pre-multiplying the alpha. So I tried with an opacity of 25% and the values came out at 1/4 of the correct ones. So, I suspect there is a bug in **OpenCV** that premultiplies the alpha.

If you look at your values, you will see that `tifffile` and `skimage` read the first pixel as:

```
[ 79  88  70 182 ]
```

if you look at the alpha of that pixel, it is 0.713725 (182/255), and if you multiply each of those values by that, you will get:

```
[ 50  63  56 182 ]
```

which is exactly what **OpenCV** did.

As a workaround, I guess you could divide by the alpha to scale correctly.

---

In case the argument is that OpenCV *intentionally* pre-multiplies the alpha, then that begs the question why it does that for TIFF files but NOT for PNG files:

```
# Create 8x8 PNG image full of rgb(64,128,192) with alpha=0.5
convert -depth 8 size 8x8 xc:"rgba(64,128,192,0.5)" a.png
```

Check with OpenCV:

```
import cv2
c = cv2.imread('a.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

In [4]: c.shape
Out[4]: (8, 8, 4)

In [5]: c
Out[5]: 
array([[[192, 128,  64, 128],
        [192, 128,  64, 128],
...
...
```

---

In case anyone thinks that the values in the TIF file are as **OpenCV** reports them, I can only say that I wrote rgb(64,128,192) at 50% opacity and I tested each of the following and found that *they all agree*, with the sole exception of **OpenCV** that that is exactly what the file contains:

- ImageMagick v7
- libvips v8
- Adobe Photoshop CC 2017
- PIL/Pillow v5.2.0
- GIMP v2.8
- scikit-image v0.14

Comment: I have no idea how to raise an issue with the OpenCV developers, so if anyone is familiar with the process and feels like raising it, please do, maybe adding an explanatory link to this answer - which can be obtained by clicking the `share` button and copying the URL.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I apologize for being too hasty in adding my comment. If what you observed is true, this behavior is not necessarily a bug per se. Pre-multiplying by alpha is a standard procedure to facilitate [image compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) so OpenCV might be doing this by default but skimage and the other libraries are not. The [docs for imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) is not clear that this is performed though.

Comment: @lightalchemist I have no issues whatsoever with your thoughts - it's a free world! Say as you please - I do! I did check what happens with a semi-transparent PNG file and found that OpenCV does NOT pre-multiply that format (I have updated my answer above) - so my feeling is either that the TIFF pre-multiplying behaviour is a bug, or OpenCV is inconsistent.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added a "answer" (actually more of a speculation) as to why OpenCV behaved the way it did in this situation. I wrongly implied that pre-multiplied alpha is the way image formats that handle alpha store the data. Actually what I was trying to suggest is why premultiplying with alpha should not come across as surprising given that we do that in graphics work. It seems that it is not OpenCV that is doing the premultiplying but that it is *not* undoing it because the `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag was passed. Running out of chars but I explained why PNG was loaded properly